# Displaying array data in Google sheets vertically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is probably an easy fix but I'm not sure why the array of matching emails are being outputted horizontally and not vertically in Google Sheets. I want all the emails to be in a specific column so the must be outputted vertically with each email being in an individual cell. I tried using the split method to separate the array into individual cells but only the first email is displayed.

```
function getTheDesiredContacts() {
 var SS =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var EmailSheet = SS.getSheetByName("Threads");
 var Contacts = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("Employees").getContacts();
 var EmailsArray = [];

 var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL);
 var MaxColumnCount = 30;
 var threads = label.getThreads();
  for(var i = 0, n = Contacts.length, x = 0; i < n; i++){
   if(i < MaxColumnCount){
    EmailsArray.push([]);
   }



  EmailsArray[x] = Contacts[i].getEmailAddresses()[0];
  x++;
  }

  if (threads.length > 0) {
   for (var t=threads.length-1; t>=0; t-- ){
    var labels = threads[t].getLabels();
   }

    for (var i in labels) {
    var z= labels[i].getName();
  }

  if(z==LABEL){
    
  var EMails = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(
    GmailApp.search("label:" + labels[i].getName())).reduce(function(a, b){
        return a.concat(b);}).map(function(EMails){

        return EMails.getFrom();
         });

  var AEmail = EMails.sort().filter(function(el,j,a){
      if(j==a.indexOf(el))
      return 1;return 0
    });  


  var deDup = new Array();  
  for(var k in AEmail) {
    var str = AEmail[k].split("<").pop();
    str=str.replace(">",'');
     deDup.push(str);  
   } 
  }
}

  var matchingEM = new Array();
    for(var m in EmailsArray){

      for(var o in deDup){
        if(EmailsArray[m]==deDup[o]){
            
          matchingEM.push(deDup);
        } 
      }    
    } 

  var unq = matchingEM.filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i);
  var unique = unq.join();

  var uniqueOff = unique.split(',');
  var uniqueemails= new Array;
      uniqueemails.push([unique]);
      Logger.log("These are the matching emails: " + uniqueemails);


EmailSheet.getRange(2,4, uniqueemails.length,1).setValues([uniqueemails]);
  return uniqueOff
```

}

Comment: LABEL is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, it seems that `uniqueemails` of `EmailSheet.getRange(2,4, uniqueemails.length,1).setValues([uniqueemails]);` is `[["value1,value2,,,"]]` that `value1,value2,,,` is a string value. In this case, the values are put to a cell. This is due to `var unique = unq.join();`. In order to put the values to the row direction, the array is required to be like `[["value1"],["value2"],,,]`.

For this, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

##### From:

```
  var unq = matchingEM.filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i);
  var unique = unq.join();

  var uniqueOff = unique.split(',');
  var uniqueemails= new Array;
      uniqueemails.push([unique]);
      Logger.log("These are the matching emails: " + uniqueemails);


EmailSheet.getRange(2,4, uniqueemails.length,1).setValues([uniqueemails]);
```

##### To:

```
var uniqueemails = matchingEM.filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i)[0].map(e => [e]);
EmailSheet.getRange(2, 4, uniqueemails.length, 1).setValues(uniqueemails);
```

- In above modified script, the values are put from the cell "D2" to the row direction. This is from your script. If you want to put the values to other rows, please modify above script.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that your script currently works with no errors. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)